# How to find active directory group status

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I can find the status of active directory user using the below code.

```
var response = (SearchResponse)ldapConnection.SendRequest(userReq);

var result = response.Entries[0];
Convert.ToBoolean(
int.Parse(result.Attributes["useraccountcontrol"][0].ToString()) &
                                            0x0002)
```

While I am using for active directory groups, It is always returning null.

Can anyone suggest how to find active directory group status ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the powershell commandlet https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617196.aspx Get-ADGroup.

Comment: I am using c# to implement this.

Comment: Maybe the question should go on Stack Overflow? Most of the admin guys will use a simple scripting language for that.